# Prove that a set is countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Show using a proper theorem that the set {2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 16, 27, 32, 64, 81, … } is a countable set.**

Im lost, this is for school, but there is a huge language barrier between students and professor.  I have started it but have no idea if how i have started it is even right.

I set E = {2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 16, 27, 32, 64, 81, … n}
I made a set N = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10,... n} .. to show theres a bijection

I then make a bijection... i dont even know if thats what im supposed to do
bijection={(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(8,4),(9,5),(16,6),(27,7),(32,8),(64,9),(81,10),(n,n)}

Im not exactly what to do next.  Im wondering if i should make an equation to prove that its countable, and if so what would that equation be.

Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: Exactly what elements are in the set? Chances are that once you describe that, you have automatically built a bijection between your set and ${\mathbb N}$.

Comment: There is a theorem that says every subset of a countable set is countable, and $E \subset \mathbb {N}$ is countable.

Answer (score 7):

First you have to sort out exactly what the set $E$ is. It appears that $$E=\{2^n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}\cup\{3^n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}\;,$$ the set of positive integers that are positive powers of $2$ or of $3$. To show that $E$ is countably infinite, you need to find a bijection (one-to-one and onto map) between $E$ and $\Bbb Z^+$, the set of positive integers. The following diagram suggests one way to do it.

$$\begin{array}{rll}
n:&1&2&3&4&5&6&\dots\\
e_n:&2&3&2^2&3^2&2^3&3^3&\dots
\end{array}$$

In other words, this is a systematic listing of $E$ indexed by the positive integers: $e_1=2$, $e_2=3$, $e_3=2^2=4$, $e_4=3^2=9$, and so on. To finish the job, you need to express this correspondence precisely.

Can you come up with a regular rule for calculating $e_n$ if you know $n$? It’s perfectly acceptable for your rule to have two separate subrules, one for odd $n$ and one for even $n$.

Comment: $3_{4}$ replace $e_{4}$

Comment: @Wmmoreno: Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @Joey: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you must write it in a more specific way. Your set consists of a mix of two sequences, one having general term $2^n$ the other $3^n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. So maybe something like
$$
f(k)=\frac{1-(-1)^k}{2}\cdot 2^{(k+1)/2}+\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}\cdot 3^{k/2}
$$
[Computation of $f(k)$ for $k=1,2,...,20$ by Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%20f%28k%29=%281-%28-1%29%5Ek%29/2%2a2%5E%28%28k%2b1%29/2%29%2b%281%2b%28-1%29%5Ek%29/2%2a3%5E%28k/2%29%20for%20k=1%20to%2020)

And by the way: good luck finding the inverse!